# col-xs-offset-* not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, grid-layout

I'm trying to using col-xs-offset, however it's not doing anything! I cannot figure out why, it seems to be working in other pages, but with this particular code it just isn't. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center mobile-content menu">
  <h1>Quick Picks</h1>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <img src="../../assets/images/icons/0001chair.png" alt="Chair Icon">
          <p>Furniture Assembly</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <img src="../../assets/images/icons/movingHelp.png" alt="Moving Help Icon">
          <p>Moving Help</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <img src="../../assets/images/icons/0000hanger.png" alt="Hanger Icon">
          <p>Cleaning</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <img src="../../assets/images/icons/0008-hammer.png" alt="Hammer Icon">
          <p>Handyman</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you create fiddler for this?

Comment: Create https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what is your bootstrap version ?

Comment: it's code working. you again check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being my CSS. I was using my own margin class and I had overlooked that margin left and right was set to "0". My mistake entirely!